# PHP and Memcache - Session not work

Tags: php, session, memcached

I'm facing some problems using PHP + Memcached to handle sessions in separate servers. In fact, even on the same server.

In PHP im using pecl extension memcache. Not mecached.

My php.ini settings

```
memcache.hash_strategy = consistent
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://10.0.0.171:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=2&retry_interval=10"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain = ".homedoctorteste.com"
session.cookie_httponly =
```

The settings are exactly the same on both servers.

I created the following file on server 1

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["Test"] = "test";
    session_write_close();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

And the file server 2:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

But in two server return is a blank array.

I put the two files on the same server and the same problem happens.

Any suggestions? I've searched solutions on the internet but could not solve the problem.

**EDIT 1**
Remove whitespaces.

Comment: There is a space in file2.php `var_dump ($ _SESSION);` change it to `var_dump ($_SESSION);`

Comment: Thanks Richard...
But in the actual code, it does not exist ... is correct, $ _SESSION

Comment: It is working.
But my problem is php not creating cookies. I am resolving this.

Comment: Cookies are stored in a separate variable than Session variables.
http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: Thanks for the interest.
But my problem was different, and now i resolved this. Question closed!